# Input field placeholder horizontally cut off by IE

Tags: internet-explorer, input, field, placeholder

I am working on a Wordpress website using this thene: http://themeforest.net/item/form-responsive-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/7247184

I am having a problem with Internet Explorer (for a change..) with the input fields placeholder. The search input field placeholder is cut off (as seen on image) and I can't find a way to make it display properly. Would you please have any idea? Thanks.

[image: Input field placeholder cut off]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme uses inline Javascript in order to create the placeholder (with the events `onfocus` and `onblur`). I managed to fix the problem by removing the Javascript code and adding the attribute `placeholder` to my text fields.

For the support of Internet Explorer 9 and lower, I use the jQuery Placeholder library that you can find here: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder